# PostgreSQL Geometric box data type coordinates - how it works?

Tags: postgresql, geometry

In box type we can specify two points
As per documentation 1st one specifies upper-right corner. However, there is nothing stopping me from creating a box like:

```
INSERT INTO public.boxes VALUES ('Third', box '((2,2), (4,4))')
```

Does it mean box will get 'swapped'? and the first argument is like an anchor point, then with second one we can determine the size and rotation?

If I do it this way, would the box be at 90 degree angle?

```
INSERT INTO public.boxes VALUES ('Third', box '((2,2), (2,0))')
```

Is there a way to visualize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, the points are automatically swapped:

```sql
select box '((2,2), (4,4))', box '((4,4),(2,2))';
     box     |     box
-------------+-------------
 (4,4),(2,2) | (4,4),(2,2)
(1 row)
```

In the second case, you get a box that is a line.

```sql
select  box '((2,2), (2,0))';
     box
-------------
 (2,2),(2,0)
(1 row)
```

For the sake of comparison, using PostGIS, such polygon is invalid. Starting with a line rather than a polygon, the box would also be a real line instead:

```sql
select st_asText(st_envelope('linestring(2 2, 2 0)'::geometry));
      st_astext
---------------------
 LINESTRING(2 0,2 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explenaion. It's quite clear now how it works.